# Is COUNT_IF(x) functionally equivalent to SUM(IF(x, 1, 0)) in Presto?

Tags: sql, count, query-optimization, presto

While refactoring code, I came across [PrestoDB](https://prestodb.io/) queries which used `SUM(IF(x, 1, 0))` to count records that matched a condition.

```
SELECT
    user_id,
    SUM(IF(purchase_type = "Online", 1, 0)) AS online_purchases
FROM purchases
GROUP BY user_id
```

My first instinct was to rewrite these queries with [`COUNT_IF()`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/aggregate.html#count_if).

```
SELECT
    user_id,
    COUNT_IF(purchase_type = "Online") AS online_purchases
FROM purchases
GROUP BY user_id
```

From what I can tell, `COUNT_IF(x)` consistently resulted in better performance than `SUM(IF(x, 1, 0))` while returning the same results. However, I want to make sure there aren't any edge cases where the two functions behave differently.

Will `COUNT_IF(x)` always return the same results as `SUM(IF(x, 1, 0))`?